# Не получается асинхронная загрузка данных для маркеров карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, firebase

Пытаюсь загрузить координаты и данные меток карты с firebase хранилища. Проблема в том, что данные с firebase приходят **после** отрисовки карты и в нее не попадают.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&mode=debug"></script>
  <!-- connect to firebase and fetch data from there -->
  <script src="./js/firebase.js"></script>
  <!-- load array from file-->
  <!-- <script src="./js/arr.js"></script> -->  
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>  
  <!-- map here -->
  <div id="map" style="width:800px; height:600px"></div>      
  <!-- markers go into map -->
  <script src="./js/map.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

firebase.js

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
 ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var firebaseDB = firebase.database();
var arr = []

firebaseDB.ref('arr').once('value')
.then((snap) => {
  snap.forEach((item) => {
    arr.push({
      id: item.key,
      ...item.val() 
    })
    console.log('item pushed to arr'); 
  })
  console.log('arr', arr);
})
```

map.js

```
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap; 

function init() {

myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
  center: [56.18, 56.23],
  zoom: 4,
  controls: ['routeButtonControl'],
  behaviors: ['drag']
});

var BalloonContentLayoutClass = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<h3>{{ properties.name }}</h3>');


console.log(arr) // [] на этот момент он пустой !!!

arr.forEach(function (m) {
  var marker = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [m.coords.lat, m.coords.lon],
    {
      name: m.name,
      address: m.address,
      phone: m.phone,
    },
    { balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayoutClass }
  );
  myMap.geoObjects.add(marker);
  console.log('marker added')
  });
};
```

Если пробовать грузить json с подобной структурой `<script src="./js/arr.js">` локально -- все ок, грузит, и расставляет метки как надо

Доходило уже до того, что я `function init()` карты совал в промис firebase. Ничего не получилось )) 
`async` в загрузке скриптов тоже не помог.
Буду рад любому совету. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

так работает (неправильно я в промисе карту инитил )

```
var firebaseDB = firebase.database();
var arr = []
var myMap; 
console.log(ymaps); //is here !

firebaseDB.ref('arr').once('value')
.then((snap) => {
snap.forEach((item) => {
  dealers.push({
    id: item.key, 
    ...item.val() 
  })
  // console.log('fb pushed'); 
})

console.log(arr);

ymaps.ready(init);
var BalloonContentLayoutClass = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
  '<h3>{{ properties.name }}</h3>' +
  '<p>{{ properties.address }}</p>' +
  '<p>{{ properties.email }}</p>' +
  '<p>{{ properties.phone }}</p>'
);

// - map init -------------------
  function init() {

  myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [56.18, 56.23],
    zoom: 4,
    controls: ['routeButtonControl'],
    behaviors: ['drag']
  });

  arr.forEach(function (m) {
    var marker = new ymaps.Placemark(
      [m.lat, m.lon],
      {
        name: m.name,
        address: m.address,
        phone: m.phone,
      },
      { balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayoutClass }
    );
    myMap.geoObjects.add(marker);
    console.log('marker added')
    })
  }

})
```